# How to handle RoutedEvents in WinRT Popup

Tags: c++, xaml, windows-runtime, routed-events

I am playing a Little with Windows 8 and building Windows Store Apps. Currently I am trying to create a popup. I want to tap on a button on a (primitive) user control which is hosted as the `Child` of a `Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Primitives::Popup`.
When I tapped on the button I want to do something and eventually close the popup. As I read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh758286.aspx)

---

Routed events outside the visual tree

...
If you want to handle routed events from a Popup or ToolTip, place the handlers on specific UI elements that are within the Popup or ToolTip and not the Popup or ToolTip elements themselves. Don't rely on routing inside any compositing that is performed for Popup or ToolTip content. This is because event routing for routed events works only along the main visual tree. 
...

---

I then created an ugly solution as to pass the popup (as parent) to my custom control.

```
void Rotate::MainPage::Image1_RightTapped_1(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Input::RightTappedRoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    Popup^ popup = ref new Popup();
    ImagePopup^ popupchild = ref new ImagePopup(popup); //pass parent's reference to child 
    popupchild->Tapped += ref new TappedEventHandler(PopupButtonClick);
    popup->SetValue(Canvas::LeftProperty, 100);
    popup->SetValue(Canvas::TopProperty, 100);
    popup->Child = popupchild;
    popup->IsOpen = true;
}

void PopupButtonClick(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Input::TappedRoutedEventArgs^ e){
    ImagePopup^ imgPop = static_cast<ImagePopup^>(sender);
    if(imgPop != nullptr){
        imgPop->CloseParent();
        e->Handled = true;
    }
    e->Handled = false;
}
```

Is there any other way around? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the namespace `Windows::UI::Popups` there is the `PopupMenu`-class which provides exactly what I need. It creates a popup that is similar to a context-menu in classic Desktop-Applications.

First, create a new object using simply

```
Windows::UI::Popups::PopupMenu^ popupmenu = ref new Windows::UI::Popups::PopupMenu();
```

Afterwards, populate the popup with up to six items using

```
popupmenu->Commands->Append(ref new Windows::UI::Popups::UICommand("Do Something",
[this](IUICommand^ command){
//your action here
}));
```

Eventually, use the popup with your designated `UIElement` like

```
popupmenu->ShowAsync(Windows::Foundation::Point(xArg, yArg));
```

The documentation is available on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br208693.aspx) (rather poor, though). A sample project can be obtained from
[here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Context-menu-sample-40840351/).

Answer (score 1):

You could put the popup at the root of your UserControl like so:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="App15.MyUserControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App15"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid>
        <Popup
            x:Name="popup"
            IsOpen="True">
            <Button
                Content="Close"
                Click="Button_Click" />
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Then hide it from within the UserControl:

```
void App15::MyUserControl::Button_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    popup->IsOpen = false;
}
```

It isn't really a better approach, just different. I think you should probably use `HorizontalOffset` instead of `Canvas.Left` positioning and it is also often better to make the popup a child of some panel to get correct layout updates and soft keyboard behavior with `TextBox` controls hosted in popups.

Comment: Thank you for your idea. The reason for `Canvas::Left is that I want to use the popup on an `Image`-control, which can be freely positioned on a `Canvas`, there is actually no other layout container for this purpose.